# codeigniter sweet alert after flashing message

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have codigniter application i want to show sweet alert success message after message showing from controller.

```
   $result = array('status' => 1, 'message' => ' Successfully Registered');
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: version codigniter 3

Comment: Use sessions, you can enable the library in config/autoload.php, $autoload['libraries'] = array('sessions');